# Library-Scala on IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

How can I add a library in Scala on IntelliJ ? The code is already done with no mistake but the library is wrong apparently and for example the (*) can’t be understood by scala.

Comment: If your project a pure **IntellIj** one? or it is imported from a build tool like **sbt** or **mill**?

Answer (score 0):

Go check your build.sbt file, maybe there is some problem there which IntelliJ can you help you itself, and in case you're willing to add some libraries, also head to build.sbt and add following line:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // additional libraries here
)
```